# Synchronizing two Sql Server 2008 databases in same instance

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to synchronize two databases (DB1 and DB2) present in same instance.

Lets say if i create a table or make any changes to a existing table (e.g. altering the structure) in one database DB1, those should be reflected on the other database DB2

Please help

Savitha

Answer (score 1):

A few options...

Replication
Log shipping
Triggers

The choice depends on your other needs.